# Why do my Twilio Video Compositions start and end with black frames?

Tags: video, twilio, html5-video, mp4, twilio-video

I record a [Twilio Programmable Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video) room between two people and create a **Composition** out of the four recorded streams (two audio and two video).

**Problem:**
The resulting `.mp4` file always starts and ends with at least one black frame.
The original `.mkv` video files which were the inputs to the recording do not have this issue.

Why is this, and how to solve it?